# C# mixing the same inputs by 3 independent mixers

Tags: c#, audio, virtual, device, mixer

Good evening,
I'm facing a problem which might be easy in the end.

I've got different audio sources on a single pc: Two Teamspeak instances, one VOIP connection, sound samples and background noise. Now there are three independent Headphone devices. Each one needs to mix all the source streams.

How would you achieve this? I thought of creating virtual audio devices, sending all source's streams to them, split each stream 3 times, mix them and send them to the headphones in the end. Is that possible?

Comment: Seems like a piece of hardware might do this the best.

Comment: Take a look at DirectShow. It lets you build programmatically a graph that takes inputs (audio stream, video stream, file, ...) combine them with filters (mixer, encoder, decoder, splitter, ...) and output them in whatever format you need. ([Intro to DirectShow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390352(v=vs.85).aspx)) ([How to use Directshow with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421167/Pure-NET-DirectShow-Filters-in-Csharp))